# Expo error something went wrong could not load exp://127.0.0.1:19000

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I don't know what is wrong with expo it was working fine. Expo is not showing me my IP address so that I can connect expo client app with my PC by scanning QR code. I had tried many solution from internet but  nothing works. Below is the images of my expo client error image and my browser image.

[browser-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izR0d.png)

[mobile-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G079Q.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to everyone on stack overflow I solved my solution by myself. For others who find this error.

1. your connection should be the same on your phone and on your PC.
2. Internet connection your PC is connected to should have the firewall disabled.
3. If still a problem you see something like exp:127..... You can change your lan address and you can see it using expo start --lan. And use this command to change your URL
   set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.100 <- your ip address

Comment: powershell: `$Env:REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME="192.168.0.100"`

Answer (score 2):

If you run :

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```

and doesn't work then first run this command in your command prompt:

```
npm install --global @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0
```

before starting your app again with:

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing worked.. But When I try this
https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/#open-the-app-on-your-device

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```

It worked. Hope it helps.